# Why does `file.write(chr(128))` return errors in Python even though `print(chr(128))` works fine?

Tags: python, character-encoding, character, byte, fwrite

The question is exactly as shown in the title. My problem is that for for N=128, `file.write(chr(N))` fails and returns error: `UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\x80'.`

I think it is very weird that something that is allowed in `print()` would return an error in `file.write()`. However for N=255 it does not return an error, so it is not simply that it fails for all N>127.

The whole code for this example is:

```
N=128

print(chr(N)) #This works just fine.

file=open('output.txt','w')
file.write(chr(N))  #This one returns errors!
file.close()
```

With the following:

```
file=open('output.txt','w',encoding="utf-8")
file.write(chr(N)) #No error but output.txt is empty!
file.close()
```

It gives no errors, but the output file is empty.

My python version is Anaconda 3.6.5

Comment: How do you open the file?

Comment: what version of python are you using? Both print and write work in 2.7 and 3.7 but neither work in 3.5 for me.

Comment: I updated the question in response to both of your comments.

Comment: Just to clarify and avoid further errors: Anaconda 3 isn't the python version.

Comment: Please consider choosing the right answer to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure that you are opening the file with utf-8 encoding:

```
file = open('file_name.txt', 'w', encoding="utf8", newline='')
```

This solution works for python3.x.

Comment: Did you close the file before opening it with an editor?

Comment: Would you please clarify which Python version are you using? With 3.6.5  everything  works fine.

Comment: Updated question with close statement.